# Python: Estimating ARMA-models with arbitrary lags for AR/MA coefficients

Tags: python-3.x, statistics

I want to estimate ARMA model in python, where the AR/MA coefficients are estimated for arbitrary lags. For example: 10, 5343 for AR and 4, 39 for MA, instead of the typical 1,2,3,4,5....

Is there a package that can do this? (And preferably save the residuals)?

Comment: @Tingiskhan How can I have arbitrary lags in statsmodel? All the examples show the lag structure to be forced to 1,2,3,4,5...

Comment: Ah, sorry, didn't read your question thoroughly. Hmm, haven't seen one myself. Perhaps take a look at statsmodels implementation and modify it? And you might be better off posting this at CrossValidated instead